# Java RMI - I don't understand why there is no shared state

Tags: java, rmi

I have a problem (maybe a fundamental understanding problem), with Java RMI. I have a "server" object and man "clients". Both are RMI objects (they implement to different Remote interfaces). The clients register themself at the server, and are stored in a list. The server will later distribute some work to the clients and fetch the result.

The problem is, that the list, where the clients are stored, seems to be *not shared* (I have no better description). I.e. if one client calls the server interface and registers itself, it will be added into the list, but the call seems to be only locally.

Following is an minimal example of the code:

**IRemote.java**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface IRemote extends Remote {
    public void remoteCall() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**RemoteImple.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RemoteImpl implements IRemote, Serializable {
    public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void remoteCall() throws RemoteException {
        list.add(23);
        System.out.println("In remote call: "+list.size());
    }
}
```

**RegAndServer.java**

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class RegAndServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, InterruptedException {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        RemoteImpl impl = new RemoteImpl();
        reg.rebind("server", impl);

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Server sees: "+impl.list.size());
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        IRemote remote = (IRemote) Naming.lookup("//localhost/server");
        remote.remoteCall();
    }
}
```

If I start the server `java RegAndServer` it will output "Server sees: 0" in a loop. If I now start the client `java Client` in a different shell I get "In remote call: 1". However the server process still outputs "Server sees: 0".

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? I actually thought I had understood Java RMI :(

Comment: If you put the list in `RegAndServer` instead of `RemoteImpl` and use it from there, does it work? I'm not sure but it seems like `RemoteImpl` objects are spawned each time.

Comment: No @Viruzzo, that doesn'z work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RemoteImpl` should not be `Serializable` (you don't want to send a copy of it over the network, just the stub, and the runtime does that for you), and must extend `UnicastRemoteObject`

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRemote {
    public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public RemoteImpl() throws RemoteException {

    }
    @Override
    public void remoteCall() throws RemoteException {
        list.add(23);
        System.out.println("In remote call: "+list.size());
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the code is executed in the sever side, even though the call is made from the client, so the message "In remote call" will appear in the server log.

Comment: This did it. No that I see this I'm pretty sure I used UnicastRemoteObject in the past, too.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult to remember all the quirks of RMI. It changed quite a bit over the years to make it simpler (I still remember when we had to manually compile and distribute the skeletons and stubs, start the rmiregistry, set the codebase flag...).

Comment: @fortran It has never changed in this particular respect.

Comment: @EJB I didn't say it did, just that there were less things to do to set up an RMI application and it was easy to forget some step believing that it was removed. Obviously this is still there, otherwise my answer wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

to

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If it helps. Make it safe:

```
public class RemoteImpl implements IRemote, Serializable {
    private static volatile ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void remoteCall() throws RemoteException {
        synchronized(list) {
            list.add(23);
        }
        System.out.println("In remote call: "+list.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Really surprising. Because "list" is only one instance for whole JVM. Can you add "final" to list declaration to avoid ANY POSSIBLE list reinitialisation? ("private static final volatile ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();")